# Drupal search theme form - Change input type?

Tags: php, drupal

For the theme search box used in Drupal, the text-field is as follows:

```
<input type="text" class="form-text" id="edit-search-theme-form-1">
```

As I am developing a site for mobile, I want to change the input type of the text-field to search.

Would anybody know how to go about making this change?

Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do HTML5, which actually has a input type "search", but I don't know what the current HTML5 compatibility state of mobile browsers is. You could try to change the input type with theming.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do with the standard ways. A list of Drupal form API controls is available here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6

**textfield** is used to render <input type="text"

Perhaps the following hack on the **page.tpl.php** file in your theme would get what you need:

Immediately after the following code line on your page.tpl.php,

```
<?php if ($search_box): ?>
```

Add,

```
<?php $search_box = preg_replace ("/<input type=\"text\"/", "<input type=\"search\"", $search_box); ?>
```

It worked for me. Try. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is another nice solution to this issue that works well in D6 and D7:

```
/**
 * Changes the search form to use the "search" input element of HTML5.
 */
function tao_preprocess_search_block_form(&$vars) {
  $vars['search_form'] = str_replace('type="text"', 'type="search"', $vars['search_form']);
}
```

This snippet goes into the template.php file of your theme. In my case it's *tao*, that is why the function starts with "*tao_*". You have to rename it to match it your theme name.

Comment: Did that definately work for you? I added it to the template.php file, chaning tao to my theme name but it hasn't changed the input type

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you clear the theme cache after adding any new preprocess functions in template.php